# Why was Lyanna Mormont named after Lyanna Stark?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The Mormonts of Bear Islands has been loyal to the Starks which we come to know in Season 5. When Stannis Baratheon asked them to pledge fealty to him. A raven sent by Lady Lyanna Mormont carried a letter that announced her refusal saying, "Bear Island knows no king but the King in the North, whose name is STARK ".

Later, in Season 6 Jon Snow and Sansa Stark visited her to ask for her support when they march to the North against the Boltons. Sansa tried to flatter her and said you were named after my aunt Lyanna.

Why was she named after Lyanna Stark?

Comment: Lyanna Stark was a princess and kind of a celebrity in north and Westerors. Mormont is a smaller house as compared to Starks. People do name their kids after celebrities isn't it.

Comment: @HBhatia Lyanna Stark wasn't a Princess, she was just a noble woman. She wasn't a celebrity either, she became famous after tourney of Harrenhal and her subsequent abduction, that too because it started a war.

Comment: @Aegon But surely Lyanna Mormont was born after Lyanna Stark became famous.

Comment: @tobiasvl indeed. I'm not saying she wasn't named after the Stark girl. I'm merely clearing that she wasn't a princess and she didn't hold her fame when she was alive

Comment: @aegon she's only 'just a noblewoman' if her father is 'just a lord'; if you recognise her father as 'King in the North' then she would be a princess

Comment: @AnotherDave, nobody considered rickard stark as KitN. There was no kiTn since Torrhen Stark. Robb proclaimed himself as such but he was self proclaimed, it wasn't.recognized by anyone outside his realm (riverlands became part of his realm). So no, Lyanna was by no means a princess

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Simply to win your Lord's favor, or to honor him in a way

ADWD, Chapter 3, Jon

> Jon took a knee. The king frowned at him, and rattled the parchment
>   angrily. 
>  “Rise. **Tell me, who is Lyanna Mormont?” 
>  “One of
>   Lady Maege’s daughters, Sire. The youngest. She was named for my lord
>   father’s sister.”  
>  “To curry your lord father’s favor, I don’t
>   doubt. I know how that game is played.** How old is this wretched girl
>   child?”

Comment: Heh +1. I came here to answer with the same quote. But you must note however, that's Stannis' observation which doesn't have to be true. He is a bitter man.

Comment: Another thing, OP never mentioned books tag so you should have first asked the OP if books only answers are okay. This dialogue never happened in the Show IIRC

Comment: @Aegon, it's bad enough that us book readers get to wait another year to get the REAL story of "Winds of Winter" while all the TV watchers are chattering about "Season 6."  You don't *also* get to stop us from answering questions with the *real* source!  :P

Comment: @Wildcard You think WoW will be released next year? :P  You are very optimistic person, my good Ser. :D Personally I detest the show-heresy as much as the next guy but it's just a matter of basic policy, since the show and books have gone in very different directions, a question tagged with show-tag must be answered with show references, unless the OP explicitly says s/he is fine with books or adds the book tag.

Answer (score 4):

She is only mentioned in the books so i can't quote anyone but i firmly believe its because of their fierce loyalty to the Starks, that Maege Mormont the mother of Lyanna Mormont named her daughter after Ned Starks younger sister to honor her.
Maege Mormont and her oldest daughter died in support for rob stark so it shows how much she supported the Starks.